# Provide a path to pandas under windows

Tags: python, pandas, path

Hi I have the following code that uses the os.path.split() and os.sep in order to create the path to the file that pandas has to open and still he cannot open it. More in detail I have used recursively os.path.split to create a list with all the folders comprised in the file path:

```
def PathDisintegrator(Inp_File):
    Folders = os.path.split(Inp_File)
    LastFolder = Folders[1]
    RootPath = Folders[0]
    Dirs=[]
    while not(LastFolder==''):
        Dirs.insert(0,LastFolder)
        Folders = os.path.split(RootPath)
        LastFolder = Folders[1]
        RootPath = Folders[0]
    Dirs.insert(0,RootPath[:-1])
    Dirs=Dirs[:-1] 
    return(Dirs)
```

and then I have linked them to a new file that I have created using recursively folder+os.sep:

```
def PathAndFile(Folders,File):
    FileOut=''
    for item in Folders:
        FileOut=FileOut+os.sep+item
    FileOut=FileOut[1:]+os.sep+File  
    return(FileOut)
```

And the main looks like:

```
import subprocess as sb
import os
from tkFileDialog import askopenfilename 
curfolder=os.getcwd()
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import pandas as pd
Inp_Filename=askopenfilename()
Job_Directory = os.path.split(Inp_Filename)[0]
Folders=PathDisintegrator(Inp_Filename)
LDPE_angle=0
FinalDisplacement=6.2328
RateTest=0.01
Width=15.0e-3;
Length=100.0e-3;
ThicknessLDPE=53.0E-06;
ElemNumLength=100.0;
ElemNumWidth=40;
PythonScript=sb.Popen(["abaqus.bat","python","ExtractNumData.py","DOWLEX_PET_LAMINATE_PROTO_REFERENCE_SI_Version_2_Revision_1_MDangle0_Rate001.odb"],stdout=sb.PIPE,stderr=sb.PIPE,cwd=Job_Directory)
Resultfileeeeeee=PythonScript.communicate()[0]
ResultFile2=PathAndFile(Folders,Resultfileeeeeee)
ResultsTemp1=pd.read_csv('D:\\Abaqus_Runs\\DOWLEX_PET_LAMINATE_PROTO_REFERENCE_SI_Version_2_Revision_1_MDangle0_Rate001_MOVING_NODE_out.csv')
ResultsTemp0=pd.read_csv(ResultFile2)
```

But indeed the command `pd.read_csv(ResultFile2)` fails with the code IOerror the file doesn't exist where instead the command `ResultsTemp1=pd.read_csv('D:\\Abaqus_Runs\\DOWLEX_PET_LAMINATE_PROTO_REFERENCE_SI_Version_2_Revision_1_MDangle0_Rate001_MOVING_NODE_out.csv')` succeeds. 
What is the error in my code?

Thanks in advance for your support.

Luca

Comment: Can you not print out `ResultFile2` and compare them?

Comment: And what is `ResultFile2` when you print it? You should at least provide this

Comment: Also look into `os.path.join` for joining paths together.

Comment: ResultFile2 is *.csv file. And I have tried also join that doesn't work, morevoer I cannot use join in an iterative fashion since doesen't work well with "\". Insteed I think that the issue is in the management of the Drive letter "D:", but how to solve it?

Answer (score 0):

I have faced a similar issue with paths under windows and prefixing the path string with an `r` resolved my issue: `ResultsTemp1=pd.read_csv(r"path\to\file.csv")`